# Sending emails (Gmail)

Tags: c#, email, smtp

This code worked few weeks ago, but when I try it now it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.com", "password");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("mail@domain.com", "mail2@gmail.com", "Subject", "Body");
        mail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        client.Send(mail);
```

Error is: SMTPException was Unhandled:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The operation has timed out.

Comment: What's actually going wrong? Any error codes or exception details you can share with us? Otherwise it will be very hard to diagnose a mystery issue.

Comment: SSL should be port 465. [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=nl)

Comment: Probable your reached the limit https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Comment: has your server been blacklisted? You may need to log into gmail via the browser on the server and tell gmail to trust it.

Comment: I've edited my question so there's what error occurs.

Comment: How to check if I've got blacklisted?